# If $p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ then $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $a^2 \leq 3b$

Tags: real-analysis

I know $p$ is surjective and continuous, but I'm not sure how that inequality $a^2 \leq 3b$ is gonna help me with the function being injective and its inverse being continuous. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: **Hint:** When are the roots of the derivative real (and distinct)?

Comment: oh right, got it! thaank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It’s a cubic with positive leading term, so either it has a local maximum and, at some point to the right of that, a local minimum, in which case it’s not injective, or it’s more like $y=x^3$ and *is* injective. Look at its derivative, $3x^2+2ax+b$; under what circumstances can it be $0$?

Answer (score 0):

the derivative $p^\prime(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b \ge 0$ if the discriminant $4(a^2 - 3b) \le 0.$ that is if $a^2 \le 3b.$ that make $p$ an increasing function so that it is 1-1.